# Running PowerShell script which contains Get-WmiObject via c# .NET core

Tags: c#, powershell

I have one third party script, which I need to run from the .NET core application.

When I try to run the application following error, come.

The term 'Get-WmiObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
public static void RunPowershellCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();
                using (var ps = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
                {

                    ps.Runspace = runspace;
                    Command queryWmi = new Command(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Data Migration Assistant\SkuRecommendationDataCollectionScript.ps1");
                    queryWmi.Parameters.Add("ComputerName", CompName);
                    queryWmi.Parameters.Add("OutputFilePath", OutPutPath);
                    queryWmi.Parameters.Add("CollectionTimeInSeconds", time.ToString());
                    queryWmi.Parameters.Add("DbConnectionString", DBString);

                    ps.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
                    ps.Invoke();
                    ps.Commands.AddCommand(queryWmi);
                    var commandResults = ps.Invoke();

                    Debug.WriteLine($"PS command result {commandResults.Count} lines");
                    foreach (var commandResult in commandResults)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(" Command Result : " + commandResult);
                        MessageBox.Show(commandResult.ToString());
                    }
                    if (ps.Streams.Error.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Errors:");
                        foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Command Error : " + error.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And this code will run on the Windows platform only with no need to be cross-platform. Please help. I have been trying for the last 3 days with no success.

Comment: If the PowerShell version you are running under is PowerShell Core, you will need to change the [`Get-WMIObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) calls to the corresponding [`Get-CIMInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7) calls.

Comment: Yes, WMI literally has "Windows" in its name, so you need to replace the command, as @JeffZeitlin said. You should include the command in your post, or open another question.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin I can not change the command because it is in powershell scripts and which is third party.

Comment: If you can't change the script, then you have to not run it under PowerShell Core; while `Get-WMIObject` still works under Windows Powershell 5.1, it has been deprecated since Windows PowerShell 3.0, and has been entirely removed from anything later than 5.1.

Comment: The only way you can do this without much pain is to retarget your app to .NET Framework.

Comment: @Ian Kemp Is there any simplest way to retarget my app to .net Framwork because lots of development is already done and this requirement came in the last moment

Comment: @IanKemp - That won't actually help if the querent is running with PowerShell Core; they will still have to run with Windows PowerShell 5.1 to be able to use `Get-WMIObject`.